# C++ Integer removes string from *char[]

Tags: c++, string, pointers, int, string-literals

I'm trying to read in several values into my C++ program.

When I enter in a 1 digit number (at the bottom of my code) I'm fine.

However, if I enter a 2 digit number, like "10", the message (the second thing I enter) becomes erased.

Here is my code:

```
char * args[6];
unsigned time = 5;
char input[5];   // for string input
string message= "message";
//these strings and *chars are tempary strings for the purpose of reading in data
string temp;
char *temp2 = " ";
char *temp3 = "empty pointer";

     args[count] = "-m";
    count ++;

    //Prompt for the message
    cout <<endl<<"Alright, Please enter your message: "<<flush;
    getline(cin, message);
    cout <<endl<<endl;
    message.append("\"");
    message = "\""+message;
    //we can't use the string, so we copy it to temp3.
    strcpy(temp3, message.c_str());
    //Now we input the string into our array of arguments
    args[count] = temp3;
    count ++;


    cout <<"Please enter time  "<<flush;
    getline(cin,temp);

    //validate input utnil its an actual second.
    bool done = false;
    while (done == false){
        for(unsigned i = 0; i < temp.length() & i < 5; i++){
            input[i] = temp[i];
        }
    done = CheckInteger(input, input);
        time = atoi(input);
        if (done == true & time < 1) {
            cout <<"Unable to use a number less than 1 seconds!  "<<endl;
            cout <<"Please enter the number of seconds?  "<<flush;
            done = false;
        }else if (done == false){
            cout <<"Please enter the number of seconds?  "<<flush;
        }else{
        break;
        }
        getline(cin,temp);
    }
    cout <<endl<<endl;
    time = atoi(input);
    //timer argument
    args[count] = "-t";
    count ++;

    // enter the time need to comvert from int to string.
    ostringstream convert;
    convert <<time;
    temp = convert.str();
    //need to convert from string to character
    strcpy(temp2, temp.c_str());

    args[count] = temp2;
    count ++;
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: "`//we can't use the string, so we copy it to temp3.`"? ***Why*** can't you use `string`?

Comment: why are you passing input in twice? `done = CheckInteger(input, input);` what does this function do?

Comment: I don't use a string because I end up getting a process dump when I use string.  Also, I pass the 2 inputs in twice, int CheckInteger because, one is a pointer and the other one isn't. I know it isn't the most efficient method, but it does what I need it to do.

Comment: "I don't use a string because I end up getting a process dump when I use string.": Then that is the problem you need to fix. You shouldn't need to use all of those `char*`s.

Comment: Change your `args` array into an `std::vector<std::string>` and your code will shrink by at least a half.

Comment: @bitmask: [Closer to losing 1/3 than 1/2](http://ideone.com/KV5DL6), but yes... definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`strcpy(char* destination, const char* source)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/) copies the `source` string into the array pointed by `destination`. But you are calling `strcpy(temp3, message.c_str());` that tries to copy the string into the pointer to constant string literal: `char *temp3 = "empty pointer";`, which leads to **undefined behaviour** [1]

Change `temp3` from pointer to an array that will be just initialized with this string literal:

```
char temp3[] = "empty pointer";
```

or even better: use `std::string` instead.

---

[1] **C++03 Standard 2.13.4 String literals** (selected parts)**:**

> **§1** An ordinary string literal has type “array of *n* `const char`” and static storage duration
>
> **§2 The effect of attempting to modify a string literal is undefined.**

Comment: Thanks. It was the pointer that was causing problems. I changed it to char temp3[];

Comment: @user1797035: This is a bad idea. If the user enters a message that is longer than "`empty pointer`", then you'll overrun the buffer and corrupt your stack. This entire function can and should be implemented using `std::string`. [Q.E.D.](http://ideone.com/KV5DL6)

Comment: @Johnsyweb: Nice rewrite. Small nitpick, though: [stoul](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul).

Comment: @bitmask: Thanks. I merely fixed the existing code, rather than rewrite it entirely.